# iOS app provisioning profiles and Microsoft Endpoint Manager (Intune)

Tags: ios, ios-provisioning, intune, in-house-distribution

We use Microsoft Endpoint Manager aka Intune as mobile device management system and have rolled out a bunch of iOS line-of-business apps.

The expiration date of the provisioning profiles is near and a warning is shown on the "iOS/iPadOS apps" page of Intune hinting about that:
[image: Intune Warning]

We used this guide to upload a new provisioning profile: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/intune/apps/app-provisioning-profile-ios

The provisioning profile is shown on the "iOS app provisioning profiles" page of Intune with the correct expiration date.

Our expectation was, that the warning about the near expiration would disappear on the "iOS/iPadOS apps" page, but it is still here.

We hoped, that the upload of a new provisioning profile would spare us of the need to create a new .ipa file for the in house apps.
Can somebody confirm, that this works or will the apps be invalid after the expiration date?

Answer (score 0):

As the expiration date has passed now, I can confirm that the apps are still working, although the status now changed to "expired".